# When I run wdio-runner, I have got "wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker" warning message

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I have had a problem with WebdriverIO & Cucumber.

I used latest version of WebdriverIO (`@v5.x.x`) and Cucumber v4. When I run my test suite, the console shows me a warning message. Also, no Cucumber `.json` data file is created in the process.

The warning message:

> WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker:

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.4.16",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.4.17",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.4.17",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.4.14",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.4.15",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cucumber": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "wdio-cucumber-framework": "^2.2.8",
    "webdriverio": "^5.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

**Here is console output:**

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\Git\Aydes-Wdio\e2e\node_modules\@wdio\cli\bin\wdio.js Conf/wdio.conf.js --suite Test
2019-02-18T08:52:46.911Z DEBUG wdio-config: @wdio/sync not found, running tests asynchronous
2019-02-18T08:52:47.729Z DEBUG wdio-cli:run: Run suite with config Conf/wdio.conf.js and params { _: [ 'Conf/wdio.conf.js' ],
  suite: [ 'Test' ],
  '$0': 'node_modules\\@wdio\\cli\\bin\\wdio.js' }
c  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
  1 running, 0 passed, 0 failed, 1 total (0% completed)
c
Stdout:
2019-02-18T08:52:48.887Z INFO wdio-cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2019-02-18T08:52:51.456Z INFO wdio-local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: Conf/wdio.conf.js,--suite,Test
2019-02-18T08:53:05.197Z DEBUG wdio-local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 0
2019-02-18T08:53:05.199Z INFO wdio-cli:Launcher: Run onComplete hook

Stderr:
2019-02-18T08:53:00.118Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"suite:start","cid":"0-0","uid":"Demo Page of Google1","title":"Demo Page of Google","pending":false,"parent":null,"type":"suite","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"keyword":"Feature"}, ignoring!
2019-02-18T08:53:00.137Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"suite:start","cid":"0-0","uid":"Search a text in Google3","title":"Search a text in Google","pending":false,"parent":"Demo Page of Google1","type":"suite","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"keyword":null}, ignoring!
2019-02-18T08:53:00.140Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"test:start","cid":"0-0","uid":"I open \"http://www.google.com\" the website4","title":"I open \"http://www.google.com\" the website","pending":false,"parent":"Search a text in Google3","type":"test","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"duration":0,"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"featureName":"Demo Page of Google","scenarioName":"Search a text in Google","keyword":null}, ignoring!
2019-02-18T08:53:04.769Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"test:pass","cid":"0-0","uid":"I open \"http://www.google.com\" the website4","title":"I open \"http://www.google.com\" the website","pending":false,"parent":"Search a text in Google3","type":"test","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"duration":4629,"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"keyword":"Given "}, ignoring!
2019-02-18T08:53:04.771Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"suite:end","cid":"0-0","uid":"Search a text in Google3","title":"Search a text in Google","pending":false,"parent":"Demo Page of Google1","type":"suite","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"duration":4634,"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"keyword":null}, ignoring!
2019-02-18T08:53:04.773Z WARN wdio-cli: Can't identify message from worker: {"event":"suite:end","cid":"0-0","uid":"Demo Page of Google1","title":"Demo Page of Google","pending":false,"parent":null,"type":"suite","file":"Web\\Features\\Test.feature","err":{},"duration":4655,"runner":{"0-0":{"maxInstances":5,"browserName":"chrome"}},"specs":["D:\\Git\\Aydes-Wdio\\e2e\\Web\\Features\\Test.feature"],"tags":[],"keyword":null}, ignoring!

Test Suites:     1 passed, 1 total (100% completed)
Time:          16.46s


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found my mistake.

Here is explaining why cucumber not running on wdio V5

> To use Cucumber you have to use WebdriverIO v4 until the framework has been migrated to v5